# imshow/imwrite changes all pixel values to 1

Tags: matlab, octave, image-preprocessing, octave-gui

I have a Matlab dataset saved with `.mat` that I'm trying to process in Octave GUI. The data consist of images and I want to save them in a JPG format (or any other image format), but I'm having this strange behavior when trying to displaying or writing the images.
this is how part of the image displays as an array:

```
    91    90    91    88    93
    88    91    86    81    88
    93   100    90    85    91
    93   100    94    93    96
    87    87    87    87    89
```

But when I write the image

`imwrite(img, 'D:\image_test_1.jpg')`

and read it again

`img_read=imread('D:\image_test_1.jpg')`

I end up with this:

```
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
```

I tried searching for the cause, but couldn't find a definitive answer or clarification to this problem. Even when I'm using `imshow` to display the image I end up with a blank image.

What happened to all the pixel values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Configuring as `uint8` Image

To indicate that this image is using an 8-bit scale/format we can caste the array as an `uint8()` (unsigned 8-bit integer). This format will assume the intensity values range from 0 to 255 (typical JPG format). I think the reason for the array showing up as 1s is that Octave is trying to parse the array as a double ranging from 0 to 1. Therefore the results of the array are reaching the ceiling of 1 since all the intensity values of the `Image`/`img` array are out of range (maxed out). Alternatively we can convert the array to double using the `im2double()` function or diving the original array by 255.

[image: 8-Bit Image Result]

```
Image = [91  90  91  88  93; 
         88  91  86  81  88;
         93  100 90  85  91;
         93  100 94  93  96;
         87  87  87  87  89];

Image = uint8(Image);

imwrite(Image, 'D:\image_test_1.jpg')
imshow(imread('D:\image_test_1.jpg'),'InitialMagnification','fit');
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for the precise answer!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Comment: one more question :). I found that I can specify the quality of t image here https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html. but when I set quality value I'm having an error. Do you have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: @salRad `imwrite(Image, 'D:\image_test_1.jpg','Quality',20)` seems to work for me on MATLAB.